# Self-destructive users: let them go or bring them back?

Tags: discussion, site-policy

I just want to know how does the site want to approach self destructive users?

A self destructive user in this context is a user who has contributed to the site and now wishes to delete their question or vandalize it.

Should anything be done?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by self-destructive users?

Comment: You mean folks who delete their posts? Folks who do themselves no favours and troll? More detail and sanitised context would be nice

Comment: @Ubiquitous edited

Comment: I suppose you have in mind: https://economics.stackexchange.com/q/18943/42 and https://economics.stackexchange.com/q/18816/42?

Comment: @HerrK. I dont like calling out specific users in the meta but yes.

Comment: I can't see in what way the posts in question were "contribution" to the site. They were clearly do-it-for-me type questions and hence off-topic. I suppose the OP would have wanted to delete the posts but couldn't because answers were already given. The "vandalizing" edits made by the OP clearly indicated that he/she did not wish to improve the original posts to make them on-topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having a half-arsed undergraduate-level question on the site is bad, but having a vandalised post containing a random string of characters is worse. As such, I do not think we should tolerate self-vandalism, and we should insist the people deal with posts they want rid of through legitimate means (flagging, voting, etc.).

My suggestion would be to do the following:

- roll back the edits to restore the original post (and close/delete it if necessary).
- wait and see if it's an isolated incident. I would guess that 9 times out of 10 the offender will be a one-time users and will never show up on the site again.
- repeat offenders can be dealt with via the usual tools available to moderators.

Comment: Thank you for the feed back Ubiquitous, as a less senior member of the site I appreciate the Input.